# HTML 5 Canvas image overlay repeatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to take a pattern and apply it over a png image but only cover the non-transparent part of the image similar to this one.

http://jsfiddle.net/eLmmA/1/

```
$(function() {
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 250;
canvas.height = 250;

var canvas_context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    var msk = new Image();
    msk.onload = function(){
        canvas_context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        canvas_context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
        canvas_context.drawImage(msk, 0, 0);
        canvas_context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    };

    msk.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtQrZ.png';
}
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDGFY.jpg';

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

});

The example above is really close to what I want but I need to be able to use a smaller texture image and repeat it over the none pattern image. I am not familiar with how to use canvas properly but trying to learn more about it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 250;
canvas.height = 250;

var canvas_context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    var msk = new Image();
    msk.onload = function(){

        var ptrn = canvas_context.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
        canvas_context.fillStyle = ptrn;
        canvas_context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        canvas_context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        canvas_context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
        canvas_context.drawImage(msk, 0, 0);
        canvas_context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";


    };

    msk.src = $('#base_url').data('base')+'assets/themes/img/download.png';
}

img.src = $('#base_url').data('base')+'assets/uploads/thumbs/1381413411Purple-Night-Owls-thumb.jpg';


$('#itemPreview').html(canvas);
```